# ASP.NET Getting a blank page after submitting a form (beginner)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make some game, I'm not going to explain what is it because it's not really important, anyway, the problem is the following form:

http://pastebin.com/8XwdDFWY

after submitting that form I'm getting a blank page.

Here's the server side code which that form navigates to:

http://pastebin.com/tfeAMxrF

Thank for helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you use the IsPostBack that is stop from showing the data after the post back. Ether remove it, ether use asp.net controls that "remembers *" the content after the post back.

```
<%
    // this part is blocked as it is, after the post back
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Request.Params["number"]);
        string name = Request.Params["fname"];
        int points = CalcPoints(name, n);
     %>
     Hello <%=name%> You have chosen number <%=n%>
     The random numbers are : <%=num1 + " , " + num2 + " , " + num3%>
     You have scored <%=points%> points!
     <%
    }
    %>
```

[*] they saved into the view state

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If I remove the IsPostBack, I'm getting a null exception in the int.Parse line, what should I do then?

Comment: You should really have an else statement in there that has whatever you'd like to display when a Postback hasn't occured

Comment: @idish Use the int.tryparce()

Answer (score 2):

To backup Aristos answer IsPostBack only works when you submit to the same page. You are cross page scripting therefore it's not a postback but a new request.

- Use a single aspx page to handle the form and result (don't change the form action)
- Put the code in your code behind file
- Use a Literal or Label control to display the result